# ScrollView doesn't scroll in layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have in this order RelativeLayout / ScrollView / Relative Layout / Relative Layout and inside the last Relative Layout i have two Linear Layouts.

Don't know why this is happening. I have almost the same layout for other activity and it's working.

Here is the xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    >
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4000dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"  
        android:scrollbars="none"  
        android:background="@drawable/url" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <!-- Thumbnail Image -->

            <com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="115dp"
                android:layout_height="180dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" />

            <!-- Naslov Filma -->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/naslov"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumbnail"
                android:text="Naslov"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >

            </TextView>
            <!-- Godina izdanja Filma -->

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/releaseYear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/naslov"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/naslov"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rating_star"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_actions_rating_icon" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/url_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:background="@color/transparent_grey"
                android:text="Pogledaj insert iz filma" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/rating_star"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rating_star"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rating_star"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/rating" />

            <!-- Opis Filma -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_round_rect_shape" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="#7F0000"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <!-- Opis Filma Zavrsetak -->


            <!-- Glumci -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@drawable/layout_round_rect_shape"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutActors"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                        android:id="@+id/Image1"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" />

                    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                        android:id="@+id/Image2"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" />

                    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                        android:id="@+id/Image3"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="140dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutActors"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ime1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Ime"
                        android:textColor="#7F0000"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ime2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Ime"
                        android:textColor="#7F0000"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ime3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Ime"
                        android:textColor="#7F0000"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <!-- Glumci -->

            <!-- Slike -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:orientation= "vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                 >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:background="@drawable/layout_round_rect_shape"
                        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutImages"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                                android:id="@+id/pager"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="186dp"
                                android:fadingEdge="vertical" />

                            <com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView
                                android:id="@+id/image1"
                                android:layout_width="115dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" >
                            </com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView>    

                            <com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView
                                android:id="@+id/image2"
                                android:layout_width="115dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" >
                            </com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView>

                            <com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView
                                android:id="@+id/image3"
                                android:layout_width="115dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" >
                           </com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView>     

                            <com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView
                                android:id="@+id/image4"
                                android:layout_width="115dp"
                                android:layout_height="150dp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" >
                            </com.dusandimitrijevic.modification.TouchImageView>                            


                    </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
            <!-- Slike -->

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>      

</RelativeLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**

*Layout which has ScrollView and it is working:*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    >

    <ScrollView                 
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/url"     
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"  
        android:scrollbars="none"    
         >

        <RelativeLayout            
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"            
            >   

            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/slika"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="380dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/slika"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/slika"
                android:layout_below="@+id/slika"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:text="Orginalni naslov:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/naslov"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/datum_prikazivanja_filma"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/naslov"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/naslov"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/naslov"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/datum_prikazivanja_filma"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/datum_prikazivanja_filma"
                android:layout_below="@+id/datum_prikazivanja_filma"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Glumci:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                />

            <View
                 android:id="@+id/view"
                 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
                 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="3dp"
                 android:background="#c0c0c0"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Image1"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"                    
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica" />

                <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Image2"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"   
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"            
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"/>

                <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:id="@+id/Image3"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_horor_filmovi_ikonica"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"        
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"       
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutTextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ime1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Ime" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ime2"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Ime" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ime3"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Ime" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                 android:id="@+id/view2"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="3dp"
                 android:background="#c0c0c0"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutTextView"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:text="Opis filma:"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/opisFilma"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="TextView"             
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>           

        </RelativeLayout>   

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/watch_trailer"
        android:background="@drawable/dugme_trailer_selector"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Pogledaj trailer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is here **android:layout_height="4000dp"**. For the scrollView your content doesn't need scroll because it doesn't take more than 4000dp

Try changing it to match_parent

**UPDATE 2**

Change this

```
    <ScrollView                  
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"  
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <RelativeLayout            
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:background="@drawable/url">
```

Comment: Yes i have changed and the previous version of layout was with match_parent for height in scrollView, but it didn't work. I also set for the child height RelativeLayout of ScrollView on match_parent.

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic The scrollView child must have wrap_content in layout_height. Also try putting styles in the RelativeLayout child.

Comment: Didn't work with changing wrap_content in layout_height. I will edit my question and will update with layout which also have ScrollView and maybe you can find what i'm doing wrong in this layout and what is there okay.

Comment: `This ScrollView layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless` Getting this when move those lines of code in RelativeLayout and run also. Didn't work. Do you have maybe more suggestion?

Comment: Yes it is. @DusanDimitrijevic Remove RelativeLayout and make the ScrollView the parent moving xmlns line to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87115/discussion-between-alberto-fernandez-and-dusan-dimitrijevic).